# Can't get navbar to stop showing horizontal scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been playing around with my bootstrap navbar. Its original position was set as "fixed". Now that I have sent it to absolute there's a horizontal scrollbar that appears. How can I prevent the scrollbar from appearing? Thanks!

Keep in mind that "overflow-x: auto;" and "white-space: nowrap;" in my nav ID was just a method I tried to prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing.

```css
#nav {
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    z-index: 9999;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#logo {
    height: 45px;
    transition: all ease .5s;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#nav a {
    transition: all ease .5s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
 color: white;
} 

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
 font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bolder;
}
```

```html
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" id = "nav">
    <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" id="logo" alt="Logo Motive Digital"/></a>
        </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">       
      <li><a href="about.html" class="effect-underline">ABOUT</a></li>
      <li><a href="serivces.html" class="effect-underline">SERVICES</a></li>
      <li><a href="work.html" class="effect-underline">WORK</a></li>       
      <li><a href="contact.html" class="effect-underline">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By changing `overflow-x:auto` to `overflow-x:hidden` I was able to fix my issue.

Comment: If this is fixed your issue, please mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You should take care of its parent's `margin`, which is `body` :

```
body{
  margin:0px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this and nothing has changed. Is there anything in particular that I could do in css that would hide the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: Do you see any horizontal scrollbar here ? http://jsfiddle.net/gy0d2kwe/

Comment: No, but the code I shared is only a section of what I have coded already. I've updated my question and have added a photo with what it looks like. Hope this may help.

Comment: I should have also mentioned I'm using bootstrap as a framework.

Comment: Which version of bootstrap you are using ? Please provide a full working code in order to help .

Comment: Thank you very much for your time Ashraf. I figured the problem out myself! :)